# Кратчайший путь в графе, алгоритм Форда-Беллмана

Tags: c#, алгоритм, графы

В чём может быть ошибка? Не считает кратчайший путь, как надо

[image: Граф с 3 вершинами]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace FordBellman
{
    class Ford
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int n, s, m, k = 0, mod_e;      // mod_e - Кол-во ребер (во всем графе)
            mod_e = k;                      // k - счетчик массивов ребер
            int[] a = new int[200];         // массив начал ребер
            int[] b = new int[200];         // массив концов ребер
            int[] w = new int[200];         // массив весов ребер
            int[] d = new int[200];         // массив расстояний

            Console.WriteLine("Введите количество вершин:");
            n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Количество вершин
            Console.WriteLine("\nВведите номер стартовой вершины:");
            s = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Стартовая вершина
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) // Задание массивов ребер
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nВведите количество ребер, исходящих из вершины " +i);
                m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
                {
                    a[k] = i;
                    Console.WriteLine("\nВведите номер конечной вершины для "+ j + "-го ребра, исходящего из "+ i+ ":");
                    b[k] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("\nВведите вес "+ j+ "-го ребра, исходящего из "+ i+ ":");
                    w[k] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    k++;
                }
                mod_e++; 
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) d[i] = 999999;
            d[s] = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (i == s) i++;
                else
                    {
                        for (int j = 1; j <= mod_e; j++)
                            {
                                if (d[b[j]] > (d[a[j]] + w[j])) d[b[j]] = d[a[j]] + w[j];
                                j++;
                            }
                        i++;
                    }
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nКратчайший путь до вершины " + i + " = " + d[i]); 
            }
            Console.WriteLine(d);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: `if (i == s) i++;` - лучше не изменяйте итератор без особой надобности. Если вам нужно пропустить шаг, то используйте ключевое слово `continue`. В вашем же случае можно было бы обойтись просто `if (i != s) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Это не работает потому что, ты инкрементируешь j внутри цикла по j. Внутри цикла переменная этого цикла инкрементируется сама. А так ты проходишь не по каждой вершине в массиве и другим массивам а через 1. А так же когда записываешь данные в масивы типа: w, a и тд., которые достаются по j потом при записи необходимо добавить единицу т.к. другие массивы записывались с 1, а эти, получается с 0.
не - `a[k] = i;`
а - `a[k+1] = i;`
и с другими так же.